# Best way to find if a point is within another Vector2?

Tags: c#, vector, coordinates

I'm trying to find out if a point (mouse click) is within the boundaries of a box based on the top left x/y and bottom right x/y of the box. The position could be positive or negative. As you move up, y value **increases**, as you move down, y **decreases**. As you move right, x value increases, as you move left, x decreases.

Vector2 positions could be negative or positive depending on where is clicked.

I thought this would simply work but it doesn't seem to like negative numbers. Any suggestions? My brain is fried tonight after doing Vector arithmetic all night on other things. I wish I was one of you who seem to understand this without problem. ;)

```
if(point.x >= topLeft.x && point.y <= topLeft.y && 
   point.x <= bottomRight.x && point.y >= bottomRight.y)
{
 // is within box
}
```

*Edit*
Here is how the top left and bottom right are calculated. As it turns out, the problem was not with the above but rather I forgot to add the position.y to the top left calculation below.

```
Vector2 topLeft = new Vector2(transform.position.x - (transform.localScale.x/2),
                      transform.position.y + (transform.localScale.y/2));

Vector2 bottomRight = new Vector2(transform.position.x + (transform.localScale.x/2),
                          transform.position.y - (transform.localScale.y/2));
```

For anyone coming across this thread, the above check is correct.

Example 1:

[image: Bounding Box]

Example 2:

[image: Bounding Box 2]

Comment: Can you show how `topLeft` and `bottomRight` are assigned?

Comment: The shape is assigned a location based on its centre position. The centre of the rectangle is its world coordinates. 

topLeftX is calculated by taking half the size of the square and subtracting it from its world position. topleftY is calculated by taking its y world position and adding half of its height. BottomRightX is calculated by taking half width and adding to object's X world position. BottomRightY is calculated by taking world position and subtracting half height.

Getting half height and width is just done by getting total width or height and dividing by two.

Comment: I guess I have to take your word for it. :)
Have you verified that the values of the coordinates are what you expect them to be at the time of the `if` statement?

Comment: They appear correct but I'll run through it a sixth time. :)

Comment: *facepalm* you were correct, it was how I was calculating the topLeft, turns out I was doing the checking correct all along for whether it was within the bounds. Thanks!! I forgot to add the half height to the position for top left. I was just taking the height/2 but forgot to add + box.position.y.

Now... to pick a correct answer, so far there aren't any at time of this comment.

Comment: Glad I helped! About the answers, I've edited mine some time ago to say that the problem might lie somewhere else in the code. Also Rotem mentioned it in the discussion to his answer. It's up to you do decide what to upvote and accept. :)

Comment: You can also delete the question if you see no value in it for future visitors, and no answer could possibly be correct as you haven't posted the relevant part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using a `Rectangle` and then check if it contains the point?

```
var rectangle = new Rectangle(-100,0,100,-100);
if(rectangle.Contains(-25,-25))
{
    // is within box
}
```

For the rest, it appears your code should work. Then there may be a problem with the the assignment of the values of `point`, `topLeft` and `bottomRight`.

Comment: We're not using windows shapes with this application. Likewise, I need this to be efficient as it will be used dozens if not hundreds of times a second.

Comment: I doubt this will be inefficient, if you reuse the Rectangle object. 
But f course if you can't use shapes, this method is not viable :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you've wrongly inverted the boolean expression. It's easier to check for all cases where the click is outside the box.
Semantically, a certain point is outside of a rectangle if it is:

- Higher than the highest point of the rectangle
- Lower than the lowestpoint of the rectangle
- More left than the left side of the rectangle
- More right than the right side of the rectangle

If one of these is true, it's outside the box.

```
if( 
    clickPosition.x < topLeft.x
       ||
    clickPosition.x > bottomRight.x
       ||
    clickPosition.y < bottomRight.y
       ||
    clickPosition.y > topLeft.y
    )
{
    //Now you're sure the click was outside the box.
}
```

Comment: It's exactly the same number of checks to check for inside (using `&&`) or outside (using `||`).

Comment: @Rotem: yes, it is the same amount of checks. But generally speaking, people better understand an evaluation where the main operation is an || as opposed to &&. I have no proof for this, it's just something I've noticed a lot at work.

Comment: Yes I edited my original comment as you already fixed what I originally wrote as I was writing it, and had something else to say. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with the negative numbers is that your top left isn't your top left

if you say

```
topY = max(corner1y, corner2y, corner3y)
bottomY = min (corner1y, corner2y, corner3y)
```

after that your check will work fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using the wrong signs on the `Y` checks.
If your topleft is `50, 100` and the bottom right is `100, 50`, then `80` (y) still must be between `50` and `100`, it doesn't matter which direction your `Y` is moving in relation to the screen, as long as you're also inverting your definition of `top left`.

```
if(point.x >= topLeft.x && point.y >= topLeft.y && //flipped sign in the second condition
   point.x <= bottomRight.x && point.y <= bottomRight.y)  //flipped sign in the second condition
{
 // is within box
}
```

If you're not inverting your definition of `top left`, your original code is correct even for negative numbers.

Comment: According to the question, the Y value increases as the point moves upwards. But the second element of your if block is `point.y >= topLeft.y`. If that is a true statement, it means the click was NOT in the box.

Comment: @Flater According to the corner values OP has posted, that shouldn't matter. The entire space is "inverted"... well, only inverted if you're used to Windows screen coordinate space, but still, it all depends how OP defines their corners.

Comment: yes but not if you call your points `topLeft`. Because if the Y axis changes direction, it matters whether you check if a point's Y valye is larger or smaller. If the Y axis goes up, topLeft is the highest allowable Y value for the point. If the Y axis goes down, it's the lowest possible Y value.

Comment: Hi Rotem, in your if statement if the mouse click is greater than the top left Y then it is within the box, but this is not true because the y Value of the point would have to be lower than the top left y value. Y *increases* as you go up, not decreases.

Comment: @Euthyphro I guess it all depends as what you call `topLeft`, as Flater correctly stated. If you're still using the visual top as your top, then your original code is correct and works even for your negative example. In other words, your problem is somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Thanks Rotem, you are right the problem was in my code somewhere else. The problem was how I was calculating the top left. I forgot to add half of the height to the position and instead was simply just setting top left y as half the height, not adding position + half height.